# get terminal response and store it as a variable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

In the middle of my Node.js file I want to store the terminal response of `docker run -v ${PWD}/app.py:/app.py proj1part1dockerimage` in my file and store the output as a var. How would i go about getting a terminal response without opening a terminal?

Comment: Take a look at the ```child_process``` module here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html

Comment: I was looking into that but i cant figure out which functions sends the string into the input section of the terminal.

Comment: I think you should use the `spawn` method of child process module. You can write its stdin by doing something like `cp.stdin.write("Hello!")` where cp is the child process which you spawned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js everything is asynchronous, so you have to use a callback:

```
child_process.exec("docker run -v ${PWD}/app.py:/app.py proj1part1dockerimage",
  (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    const output = stdout.toString();
  }
)
```

But if you require it to be instant which I don't recommend:

```
const output = child_process.execSync("docker run -v ${PWD}/app.py:/app.py proj1part1dockerimage").toString();
```